# Calling constructor with braces

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Simple question about C++11 syntaxis. There is a sample code (reduced one from [source](http://probablydance.com/2012/12/16/the-importance-of-stdfunction/))

```
struct Wanderer
{
  explicit Wanderer(std::vector<std::function<void (float)>> & update_loop)
  {
    update_loop.emplace_back([this](float dt) { update(dt); });
  }
  void update(float dt);
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::function<void (float)>> update_loop;
  Wanderer wanderer{update_loop}; // why {} ???
}
```

I'd like to know, how it can be possible call constructor with curly brackets like `Wanderer wanderer{update_loop};` It is neither initializer list, nor uniform initialization. What's the thing is this?

Comment: But it is uniform initialization. Braces can be used to call constructors, though the constructor taking a `std::initializer_list` of that type is always preferred.

Comment: `// why {} ???` -- Good question. The is no reason to prefer this over `Wanderer wanderer(update_loop)`.

Comment: @ipc In some cases, it can avoid the most vexing parse.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But in other cases it can silently change the meaning of the code one time. I'm not a fan of "uniform" initialization.

Comment: @ipc sure, that is a pretty ugly feature of this initialization.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> It is neither initializer list, nor uniform initialization. What's the thing is this?

Your premise is wrong. It is uniform initialization and, in Standardese terms, *direct-brace-initialization*.

Unless a constructor accepting an `std::initializer_list` is present, using braces for constructing objects is equivalent to using parentheses.

The advantage of using braces is that the syntax is immune to the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem:

```
struct Y { };

struct X
{
    X(Y) { }
};

// ...

X x1(Y()); // MVP: Declares a function called x1 which returns
           // a value of type X and accepts a function that
           // takes no argument and returns a value of type Y.

X x2{Y()}; // OK, constructs an object of type X called x2 and
           // provides a default-constructed temporary object 
           // of type Y in input to X's constructor.
```

Comment: "Unless a constructor accepting an std::initializer_list is present,..." And if such a constructor is present?

Comment: @junvar That constructor will then take precedence. Compare `std::string s(10, 'a')` and `std::string s{10, 'a'}`.

Answer (score 9):

It is just C++11 syntax. You can initialize objects calling their constructor with curly braces. You just have to bear in mind that if the type has an initializer_list constructor, that one takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, braces-constructors do not allow narrowing, similarly to braces-initialization. 
Let's take a look at the simple constructor taking and printing an integer value:

```
class Test {
public:
        Test(int i) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
};
```

While `Test test(3.14);` compiles and outputting narrowed `3`, 
`Test test{3.14};` would not even compile:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘3.1400000000000001e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ [-Wnarrowing]
   11 |  Test test{3.14};
      |                ^
```