# C++ using {} instead of () for function call

Tags: c++, syntax, parentheses, curly-braces, function-call

In C++ I have seen a functioning library with a function with this signature

```
DocumentReference::DocumentReference(model::ResourcePath path, std::shared_ptr<Firestore> firestore)
    : firestore_{std::move(firestore)} {
    // code here removed for https://stackoverflow.com/
}
```

But the library calls the function using `{}` instead of `()`.

```
return DocumentReference{
    ResourcePath::FromString(document_path),
    shared_from_this()
};
```

What difference does calling a function with `{}` instead of `()` make?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor - ref. “class-or-identifier brace-init-list” for the specific case in the shown code. There are various other forms where braces (`{}`) can also be used for initialization, which can be navigated to from that link. The braces are _never_ used to invoke a function/method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not "calling a function". `DocumentReference::DocumentReference` is a constructor. There are many ways to construct an object and `{}` is one of those. See

- [Calling constructor with braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15396124/995714)
- [When should we use parenthesis ( ) vs. initializer { } syntax to initialize objects in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35285913/995714)
- [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/995714)

Comment: Wait, a constructor isn't a function? Since when this has changed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Syntactically speaking, `type(expr)` is a cast which eventually calls the constructor for you, it isn't actually "calling the constructor". This is also why `type{expr}` make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I wasn't able to find this out on my own as I was indeed misreading the constructor as a function and thus found no relevant results regarding () vs {} for C++ functions. I think we should leave the title of the question 'function' and not 'constructor', since {} can be used as function syntax in other languages e.g. Kotlin.

Comment: @heliam1 Technically a constructor _is a_ function like any other, but with special purpose and allowing syntax which isn't applicable with other _"normal"_ functions.

Answer (score 2):

> What difference does calling a function with {} instead of () make?

No differences in this case. Both of which just initialise the `DocumentReference` object.

It's preferable to use `{}` though.

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax